# Number of executors and executor memory to process 100gb file in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have a csv file 100gb in HDFS.and cluster of size 10 nodes 15 cores (in a node) and 64gb RAM (in a node). I could not find an article configuring number of exceutors and executor memory based on file size. Can some one help to find optimal values of these parameters based on the cluster size and input file size

Comment: If you converted the file to Parquet or ORC, it'd probably be half the size, if not smaller

Comment: yes it is good choice to convert it into orc or parquet file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct co-relationship between file input size and spark cluster configuration. Generally a well distributed configuration (Ex: take no of cores per executor as 5, and calculate rest of the things optimally) works really well for most of the cases.

**On the file side**: Make sure it's splittable. (CSV is splittable in raw and few other formats only) . If it's splittable and on HDFS, then depending on the block size of HDFS you will have the no of partitions.

Ex: if Block size is 128MB , no of possible partitions for 100GB : 800 partitions. (this is approximate, actual formula is complex)

In your case, the no of cores : 14 * 10 = 140 , so only 140 parts of your file will be processed in parallel
So, higher the no of cores you have, more parallelism you will get.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you help me to understand  in which scenario we need to go ahead with increasing executor memory?

Comment: As per my experience, I required a fat executor (40GB+) only when I had to broadcast a variable in GBs.